# Please offer a suggestion or at least take another look

Tags: discussion

The following post was recently categorized as off-topic and put on hold

https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4001/use-of-graphics-card-for-non-game-software-development

I presume to allow for the possibility of editing and reopening the question. I edited the question to satisfy the requirements given for putting it on hold

> "Technical support request — Questions asking about troubleshooting hardware or technical support for hardware are off-topic for Hardware Recommendations because the site is here to provide pre-purchase hardware recommendations and to recommend hardware for a specific task, rather than to support existing devices. You may get help on Super User." – ArtOfCode

Is there anything missing in order to have this question be considered as on-topic here?

Answer (score 2):

Not the best close reason but...

as per the help centre

> Hardware Recommendations is a community-run website to help you find a
>   specific product for your needs. That means you can ask for a
>   recommendation for hardware to perform a specific task.

You're asking for whether a piece of hardware would help with a vague task, as opposed to what hardware would help you deal with a specific task.

Comment: This. I was going to post an answer, but it's all stated here. The question asks for advice on value, rather than for a recommendation of a card.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything missing in order to have this question be considered as on-topic here?

Well that's a tricky thing to answer. In order for it to meet the requirements of this stack, you're questions must be very specific. Also, the list of possible answers must be very small. I could go into further detail but this question is off topic and will be placed [on hold]

Comment: It turns out that I will be issued a laptop, although I have some say about the hardware specs, it won't be until this week that I know more, that is, enough to update the question to make it relevant.